# Selenium Testing Django with React and Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, selenium, reactjs

I have a Django app that uses React to create a Newsfeed component.  When the React Newsfeed component mounts, it makes an ajax call to the Django API to get the current user, and sets the author of a new post to the current user.  Below is the code for the new post form React component:

```
var NewPost = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      author: 'Default Author'
    }
  },
  getUser: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url + "user/",
      dataType: 'json',
      method: 'GET',
      success: function(data){
        this.setState({author: data.fields.first_name});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error("Error with API", status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    })
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.getUser();
  },
  handleSubmit: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var author = this.state.author;
    var content = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.content).value.trim();
    if (!content) {
      return;
    }
    this.props.onPostSubmit({author: author, content: content});
    React.findDOMNode(this.refs.content).value = '';
    return;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="panel panel-default">
        <div className="panel-body">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <textarea className="form-control" ref="content" placeholder="Whats Up" rows="3" id="newpost-input" />
              <br/>
              <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" id='newpost-submit' value="Submit" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

When I test this code manually everything works the way it should. I login, make a post, and my name is displayed as the author of the post. But when I test this using Selenium, the author is 'Default Author'; it is not getting changed. In my Selenium test I login to my app with my login credentials, and everything works as it should, except that the author of the post is not being changed from 'Default Author' to my name.

At first I thought that Selenium was doing its work before the ajax call had time to finish. So I added some wait times to my Selenium tests but the author name never gets changed.  Any ideas why the ajax call seems to not be working?

**UPDATE**
Here is the relevant Selenium code:

```
class FunctionalTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def login(self):
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(LOGIN['USERNAME'])
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(LOGIN['PASSWORD'] + '\n')

    def create_post(self, content=""):
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('newpost-input').send_keys(content)
        self.browser.find_element_by_id('newpost-submit').click()

    def test_correct_author_name_is_displayed(self):
        self.login()
        self.create_post('A Post')
        self.assertIn("Jonathan", self.browser.find_element_by_id('newsfeed').text)
```

I know the login with my credentials is successful because I added `{{user}}` to my django template, and added a `print` statement to the selenium test to print the text of the body and `{{user}}` is correctly displayed as my username.

Another test I did was to see if the react function `componentDidMount` was being called. In the `componentDidMount` function I did this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log("component mounting");
    this.getUser();
    console.log("component mounted");
},
```

In addition to that I also added `console.log`s to the `success` and `error` functions of the `getUser` `ajax` call.  The `console.log`s from the `componentDidMount` function work, but the `console.log`s inside the `ajax` call do not.

Comment: are you sure it's logged in? everytime a Selenium request is made to the site it will need to re-login each time, unless you have cookies enabled and you load a profile via selenium.

Comment: How about sharing the relevent section of the selenium code

Comment: @ChrisHawkes I thought your name looked familar, I love your videos on Django and React on youtube.  Regarding your comment, as you can see in my update above I'm confident the selenium test is logging me in correctly because I added {{user}} to my django template and then printed the text of the body from selenium and {{user}} is correctly displayed as my username.

Comment: what does create_a_post do?

Comment: Thank you for updating the question But i would be really surprised if your tests ran at all in their current form. For example find_element immidiately after a form post results in an exception more often than not. Can you please complete them?

Comment: @e4c5 it runs, and the test fails, not an error, here is the output: 
AssertionError: 'Jonathan' not found in 'Default Author\nA Post'

Comment: Thanks for the compliment on my videos :).   I think it's a bit hacky, but sometimes putting in a time.sleep(2)  (1 or 2 seconds) after you enter your login data and or submit the page, Selenium may be executing too quickly for the page to load and register the latest state of your application.

Comment: sorry I see you have already tried waits :(

Comment: @Jonathan where do you add your waits? On a side note, the new Expected Conditions will probably make your tests more robust http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp